# excluding developer iAds from my apps

Tags: iphone, iad

I want to exclude developer iAds from my apps, as I don't think the revenue is worth the annoyance to my users.

I asked Apple about it, and they said there is no way to do this, and there are no plans to add one.

However, I have to wonder if there is a keyword in the exclusions that will do the trick.

Has anyone found such a keyword?

Comment: Are you saying that you want iAds in your app but you don't want them to be from developers, or are you saying that you don't want any iAds in your apps?

Comment: I want iAds, but not from developers.

Comment: So you would rather make no revenue than the lower amount that iAds for Developers provides?  Seems like you'd be shooting yourself in the foot by doing this.  Also, this isn't a programming question, but one about Apple's advertising policies.

Comment: Well, if the money were free, I'd take it.  But I think some users will disconnect from the internet to try to avoid the ads.  The fewer ads there are, the less likely they are to do that.  Also, per the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), this is on-topic as a "matter that is unique to the programming profession."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this (as far as I know).

By the way, the goal of Apple is to do Money (no joke), so they will print the best Ads they can ;-) If they don't, it's they don't have any Ad for you currently.

I'm french, and iAds isn't here (in Europe)... so think to others and do with what you have ! :-)

Good Luck.